# how can i do "soft delete" in oracle apex

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

how can i do "soft delete" - and add a hidden column deleted. And instead of actually deleting records, mark them as deleted. This way you can see where deleted = 1 to see deleted rows. Otherwise, use where deleted = 0

Comment: Maybe you need to research over on https://dba.stackexchange.com

Comment: Another term for this is "logically deleted", and you may wish to record the date it was deleted, not just a boolean.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of deleting, you'd update some column in that row and set (for example) `cb_deleted = 1`. To do that, you'd have to write your own processing procedure (because Apex would really delete that row otherwise).

For viewing purposes, add an item (a radio button would be just fine) to show deleted (that value would be `1`) or "active" (value = `0`) rows.

Report's query would then look like

```
select ...
from that_table
where cb_deleted = :P1_RB_DELETED
```

Comment: thanks @Littlefoot  for your answer,  im really new with the oracle apex and i dont know how to do so , can you please help me with the steps to do that ?

Comment: Have a read through this page, I think it will help http://www.grassroots-oracle.com/2015/12/tutorial-include-action-button-in-report.html

Answer (score 0):

You could use instead-of-triggers and a view. You would let Apex do it's operations (insert, update, delete) on the view instead of the table. The instead-of-triggers would transport the changes then to the real table in what ever way you like it to. I use this mechanism with apex to realize a history-mechanism. Just search the web for an example on instead-of-triggers ...